# Parse csv with csv-parse packages Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv

I read csv files with fs package and parse the result using csv-parse. The result is array like this:

```
[ [ 'nama_venue\tketerangan' ],
  [ 'Ruang Kelas A1.1\truang_kelas' ],
  [ 'Ruang Kelas A1.2\truang_kelas' ],
  [ 'Ruang Kelas A1.3\truang_kelas' ],
  [ 'Ruang Kelas A1.4\truang_kelas' ],
  [ 'Ruang Kelas A1.5\truang_kelas' ],
  [ 'Ruang Kelas A1.6\truang_kelas' ],
```

The problem emerges when I want to insert that data into db. Coz mysql package requires array like `[[a, b], [b, c]]` instead of `[[a\tb],[b\tc]]` in my array. How to do it thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your array is called `array`, use:

```
array.map(a => a.map(s => s.replace('\t', '')))
```

Example:

```js
const array = [[ 'nama_venue\tketerangan' ],
  [ 'Ruang Kelas A1.1\truang_kelas' ],
  [ 'Ruang Kelas A1.2\truang_kelas' ],
  [ 'Ruang Kelas A1.3\truang_kelas' ],
  [ 'Ruang Kelas A1.4\truang_kelas' ],
  [ 'Ruang Kelas A1.5\truang_kelas' ],
  [ 'Ruang Kelas A1.6\truang_kelas' ]]
  
const array2 = array.map(a => a.map(s => s.replace('\t', '')))

console.log(array2)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your csv parser is correctly parsing the newlines, but not the tab delimiter. You can do:

`parser(data, { delimiter : '\t' })`

Per the docs:

http://csv.adaltas.com/parse/

Set the field delimiter. One character only. Defaults to "," (comma).